# JavaScript Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, sum, subset

The goal is to find if any combination of integers in the array equal the largest integer in the array.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 
  arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  });
  var largest = arr.pop();
  function recursion(target,array){
    if(array.length === 0){
      return target === 0; 
    }
    var n = array[0];
    array = array.slice(1);
    return recursion(target,array) || recursion(target - n, array);
  }
  return recursion(largest,arr);        
}
```

This solution seems to works but I cannot follow it. At the bottom of the recursion function when it reaches the right side of the OR operator I would think it would almost always return false, however it continues recursing. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the or condition at the end that makes the function check all combinations.

The function shaves off a number from the array, then it checks if it's possible to find a solition either without that number or with that number.

If you for example have the array `[1,2,3,6]`, let's follow the part of the recursion that finds the solution. The code will first pick out `6` as the largest, then call the recursive function to look for the sum `6` in `[1,2,3]`.

The function will shave off `1`, and then check if either the sum `6` can be found in `[2,3]`, or if the sum `5` (6-1) can be found in `[2,3]`.

The recursive call for the second case will shave off `2` from the array, and then check if the sum `5` can be found in `[3]`, or if the sum `3` (5-2) can be found in `[3]`.

The recursive call for the second case will shave off `3` from the array (leaving it empty), and then check if `3` can be found in `[]`, or if `0` (3-3) can be found in `[]`.

The recursive call for the second case will match the condition in the beginning of the function, and return `true`.

Comment: Ok. I didn't realize it was saving the variable values as it kept executing the left side of the or operator. Is it creating a closure from not finishing the statement? Or just in getting backed up in line in the call stack? Or both?

Comment: @MattLarsh: The parameters and the `n` variable are local to the function, so each call to the function gets their own set of those. Exactly how that is implemented in Javascript is not defined, but it has the same effect as the parameters being pushed on the stack for the call, and room is made on the stack for the `n` variable.